# What charges does one risk if they share personal pictures without permission?

Tags: privacy, workplace, personal-information

This question was inspired by something I read on another Stack Exchange website.

---

Basically, Mr. Johnson works at a small company *Good Company*. His responsibility is to manage and organise the digital files stored on the company's storage devices (be it a server, a NAS, or anything).

One day, while going through the files, he stumbles on several private pictures in some random folders. The pictures are clearly depicting the boss and their partner (they both work at the company), some of which are very intimate pictures.

If Mr. Johnson decided to "teaches them a lesson" and posted their pictures somewhere online without their consent, they found out that their pictures got leaked, and they deduced that Mr. Johnson is the most likely person to have done it, **what can Mr. Johnson be charged with?**

Comment: I didn't specify any country, because I am interested in seeing how it differs. But if needed, I could focus on some specific cases.

Comment: Are you interested in just the criminal charges or the potential damages in a civil case?

Comment: @Studoku That's a good question, I didn't think about it. I was thinking about the criminal charges the perpetrator would be sentenced to.

Comment: Suddenly I wonder if this question isn't too broad because of the lack of country tag. I wouldn't be able to accept an answer since any and every answers would be valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**What can Mr. Johnson be charged with?**

In [england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales) this would be an offence colloquially referred to as [revenge porn](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/revenge-porn) contrary to [s.33 of the Criminal Justice and Courts Act 2015](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2015/2/section/33?timeline=false)

> (1) It is an offence for a person to disclose a private sexual
> photograph or film if the disclosure is made —
>
> (a) without the consent of an individual who appears in the photograph
> or film, and
>
> (b) with the intention of causing that individual distress.
>
> ...
>
> (9) A person guilty of an offence under this section is liable —
>
> (a) on conviction on indictment, to imprisonment for a term not
> exceeding 2 years or a fine (or both), and
>
> (b) on summary conviction, to imprisonment for a term not exceeding 12
> months or a fine (or both).